# React hot-loading stopped self updating

Tags: reactjs, webpack, symfony-2.8, react-hot-loader

I'm trying to implement a solution with react and symfony 2.8, but as I'm new to react I'm still in the tutorials step. Once I though I had a good enough knowledge from react I decided to try and integrate React with symfony and I was almost successful in that. I managed to get a symfony view to load react components but was unable to do live edits, and by that I mean, I have to restart webpack and press F5 to reload the page. So I decided to go back to the tutorials I made and see what I was doing wrong. When I start a new react project (by using "create-react-app projectName") to see where I failed, this project had the same problem, I had to reload the webpack so I could see the changes I made, and I know that this project was able to live-edits (because was the first tutorial I made and was working at the time), all I needed to do is to save the document and the page should automatically show the changes I made.
I think that showing the code its not important in this case because it's a fresh project by using the command I said before, but anything you need I can try to explain you or giving the code.